# Sampling a signal in 2D DFT

Tags: fourier-transform

I have a surface(square image) that I would like to aproximate as a 2d dft. Almost all implementations of $X(k) = \displaystyle\sum_{t=0}^{n-1} x(t) e^{-2 π i t k / n}$ I have seen imply that k - the number of bands and t - the number of samples would be the same and probably should be sampled in a lattice-like manner. To my knowledge the sampling is done only to assess how similar harmonic is to a signal. Why can not it be done similar to sampling a spherical function with Monte Carlo methode where we can use any number of samples to assess how similar a spherical harmonic is to the function. I don't need very big number of sinusoids so does it limit the number of samples I can take?

Comment: 2d or 1d doesn't change the maths. You can compute $X(k) = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x(n) e^{-2i \pi nk/N}$ for any $k$ (equivalently zero-padding $x(n)$ to increase $N$). But to reconstruct $x(n)$ you only need $k \in 0 \ldots N-1$ : $x(n ) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} X(k) e^{2i \pi nk/N}$. If you only know $X(k_l)$ for some irregularly spaced values $k_l$, you can estimate $X(k)$ from it using kernel density estimation and estimate $x(n)$ after that. If you want more help you need to explain your concrete problem.

Comment: Thank you. It is not like there is any particular problem. I just happened to learn about SH first and was expecting to see some similar approach in dft. Intuitively it appears the more samples we take the more accurately we can assess a resemblance of a basic function to a signal.